# I got my css webapp (reactjs - nodejs) working perfectly at localhost but when I upload the files to heroku it changes the way they look

Tags: css, reactjs, heroku

The app runs perfectly, the only problem are the css files.
I've been doing the imports of the css files like this:
***import "/my/css/route/file"***
and most of the css worked fine, but there are some peaces of code that does not take it good.

I've changed to:
***require("my/css/route/file")***
and neither works.

Here's a piece of code of both import with the exact route I use:

```
import "../../css/a_myCSS/myStyle.css";
require("../../css/a_myCSS/myStyle.css");
```

I've been looking for errors like this on heroku and I think the problem it's at the pipeline process but I'm not sure...

Some examples of how it looks:
[localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7avvp.png)
[heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/synsb.png)
The left side is for the localhost and the right side is for the heroku
[cssCompare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBLAP.png)

Comment: you should upload the full code. I think you should clarify extention file such as file.css when use `import`

Comment: Yes, I use the full route using import file.css and require(file.css) aswell. What code do you need?

Comment: try with `./my/css....`

Comment: I edited the question with the exact code I use to import/require the css's